# How can i let my rigid body simulations continue for longer?

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

My timeline will only go upto 350 frames then the simulation will end. I have tried to increase the end time for it but it will not work is there another way i can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the start and end frames of a rigid body simulation under the *Rigid Body Cache* rollout of the *Scene* properties tab.

[image]